# Why is symplectic geometry the natural setting for classical mechanics?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

I was reading [this](http://math.mit.edu/~cohn/Thoughts/symplectic.html) very nice document, to understand why symplectic geometry is the natural setting for classical mechanics. I more or less understood why there is naturally a 2-form that arises. However, I didn't really understand the argument towards the end :

> [...]All that remains is to explain why ω should be closed, i.e., why dω =
>   0. Unfortunately I don't see how to explain that without slightly more notation, but it won't be too bad.
>   This requirement corresponds to a slightly more subtle issue, namely
>   that the laws of physics should not depend on time. Let Ft denote the
>   time-t flow along the vector field corresponding to some Hamiltonian
>   H. One natural way to get the laws of physics at time t is to look at
>   the pullback Ft*ω. We want it to equal ω. Clearly it does so at time
>   0, so to check that it always does we simply differentiate with
>   respect to t, as follows.

What does he mean by : "One natural way to get the laws of physics at time t is to look at the pullback $F_t^*\omega$"? Why is that? And why do we want it to be equal to $\omega$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this setting $\omega$ **is** "the laws of physics" (more precisely it is "the laws of classical mechanics"). It is the object that turns energy $H$ into dynamics $V$ (which is what Newton's laws do in the more usual setting). Also,  in this setting $F_t$ is the diffeomorphism that "moves the clock froward by $t$ seconds", so $F_{t}^{-1}$ "moves the clock backward by $t$ seconds", and   $F^*_t$  moves any physical quantity represented by a  covariant tensor field (like $dH$  or $\omega$) back to what it was $t$ seconds ago. Various objects (like some other function $K$ on $M$) may change over time, so their pullback will not be the same as the object itself, but saying that the "law" does not change precisely says that $F^*_t \omega=\omega$.

Comment: But  what exactly is $F_t$? Is it the flow such that $F_t(p)$ is the position in the phase-space after time $t$ if we started initially (at $t=0$) in the state $p$?

Comment: Yes (assuming that energy function is the given $H$).

Comment: Is there many possible choice of $\omega$ for a given problem? In my opinion there should be only one, because there is only **the** law of physics, no?

Comment: Maybe a better way to put it is that $\omega$ is the law(s) of mechanics as applied to a particular system.  For example, if a system has configuration space $Q$ and phase space $T^*Q$ then there is a canonical symplectic form on $T^*Q$ which encodes laws of mechanics for that system.

Comment: Just one more thing : So the idea is to map the 1-fom dH to a vector field V (that models the dynamics), so basically to have a map $D:T^*M \rightarrow TM$. But what does he mean by saying, we can consider the dual approach. I.e. exhibiting a map from $F : TM \rightarrow T^*M$? Is this the same? If $A$ is a vector space, giving the map from $A$ to $A^*$ is the same as giving a map from $A^*$ to $A$?

Comment: Not quite. In general, $Hom(A, A^*)=A^*\otimes A^*$ ($A=T_p M$ means we are looking at forms) and $Hom( A^*, A)=A\otimes A$  ($A=T_p M$ means we are looking at bi-vectrofields). In fact, that is why one can argue that Poisson geometry is the natural setting for classical mechanics. However, to give *isomorphism* from $A$ to $A^*$ is of course the same as to give one from $A^*$ to $A$. If your bivectorfield is not an isomorphism, then the dynamics is restricted -- no matter what energy is chosen, every point only moves within its symplectic leaf. So maybe it is natural to pick it to be an iso.

Comment: Ok. It is more clear, but I am not sure that I understood correctly. So first we were looking to map variation in the Hamiltonian to some dynamics, i.e. we were looking for a map $T*M \rightarrow TM$. Now are you explaining that it is natural that this map is an isomorphism? If it is not, than the movement will only take part in a proper submanifold? What would be the problem with that (probably a silly question but...)? How can you see that no matter what the energy is the dynamics is in a proper submanifold if it is not an isomorphism?

Comment: 1) I think you understood correctly. 2) I don't think it's a problem to have movement in a  submanifold, but then for most purposes you can ignore the rest of the space and work on the submanifold.3)The map is to velocities. If map is not iso, that means that velocity is only allowed to be in a subspace - a local restriction. To see that the movement is globally in an (immersed) submanifold you need to basically use Jacobi identity for Poisson bracket (this is the replacement of the $d\omega=0$ condition) to prove an integrability condition and then use Frobenius theorem (plus some more work).